# Load HAML partial from another HAML file

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Is it possible in HAML to use haml in haml like templates?

example:

- menu.haml
- layout.haml
- page1.haml

page1 for example:

```
haml: menu.haml

%p 
  content
```

as you know, get our layout from layout.haml (like a banner and such).
I want to make a seperate menu part in a haml file. Is this even possible?

extra info:

- using sinatra webframework

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Assuming `menu.haml` in located in your views directory, and assuming it takes no locals, it's as easy as this:

```
= haml :menu
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
= Haml::Engine.new(menu.haml).render(self)
```

Where `self` is current context in your view files

Comment: There is a syntax error in this code. What is `menu.haml`? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can even render haml partials like so:

> = render :partial => "sidebar"

Answer (score 1):

You can add [partials](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) as embedded `haml`inside existing template:

For example, you have a view file called `view.html.haml`:

```
%h2 This is the first view
%h4 the following line 'inserts' an external code inside the view
=render 'partial'
%h4 this text will appear next of partial
```

end the partial code `partial.html.haml`:

```
%p
  %span This is the external code
```

so, the final view when it is compiled will be:

```
%h2 This is the first view
%h4 the following line 'inserts' an external code inside the view
%p
  %span This is the external code
%h4 this text will appear next of partial
```

The text inside quotes next `render` y the path to partial inside `app/view` folder in Rails without file extension, and you can add options, such as `:layout` or `:partial`. About Sinatra the path to partial works as the same way, just change the views path.